# Error #1064 SQL Syntax

Tags: mysql, sql

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(14) NOT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=38987' at line 14

There is a problem is this sql snip that I need help with. Thanks!

```
--
-- Table structure for table `chat_lines`
--

CREATE TABLE `chat_lines` (
  `id` int(9) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `userid` int(9) NOT NULL default '0',
  `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `message` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `staff` varchar(20) NOT NULL default '',
  `private` varchar(20) NOT NULL default '',
  `timesent` timestamp(14) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=38987 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: `TIMESTAMP` instead of `TIMESTAMP(14)`; that type does not need a size specifier.

Comment: and if you give size specifier, then it should not be more than 6

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE `chat_lines` (
  `id` int(9) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `userid` int(9) NOT NULL default '0',
  `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `message` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `staff` varchar(20) NOT NULL default '',
  `private` varchar(20) NOT NULL default '',
  `timesent` timestamp NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=38987 ;
```

See if that helps.